# $zen-gutter-method not working

Tags: sass

Has anyone managed to get $zen-gutter-method to work?

In general, it's a mystery to me why setting variables sometimes works and sometimes does not work in the zen grids system.  Here's what I'm doing...

```
$zen-gutter-method: margin !global;
#featured {
  @include zen-grid-item(3, 1, left, 5);
}
```

I've also tried a number of different variations on the above, and nothing works.  Gutters are still using the 'padding' method.

For the most part, I set $zen-auto-include-item-base to false, but I've also tried it set to true.

Comment: Note that the mixin you're using has an argument that allows you to override this setting on a per mixin call basis.

Comment: @cimmanon If indeed it is somehow possible to specifiy the gutter method on a per mixin basis, I don't see that documented anywhere, so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You read the source: https://github.com/JohnAlbin/zen-grids/blob/master/sass/zen-grids/_grids.scss

Comment: I updated to the latest zen-grids gem, and had a look at the source, but still cannot set a gutter method either by passing an argument to zen-grid-item(), zen-grid-container(), or declaring it in a variable with the global flag.  I just can't get the gutter method to work by any means thus far.

Comment: FYI, I posted an issue to the zen grids project: https://github.com/JohnAlbin/zen-grids/issues/80

Answer (score 0):

The gutter method was not working because it was added in v2 of zen grids, and I was using v1.  In v2, the gutter method works when passed as an argument to zen-grid-item, like so...

```
#featured {
  @include zen-grid-item(3, 1, left, 5, 10px, margin);
}
```

However, FYI, it does not seem to work when passed to zen-grid-item-base, and setting the $zen-gutter-method variable seems to have no effect.